# Whether to save form input to state in onChange or onSubmit in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started learning React and came across this problem, and I think there should be a conventional way to solve it.

I have a `form` that contains an `input`. I started off making the `input` a controlled component, binding its value to a state variable and updating the state in the `input`'s `onChange`. However, this `form` is part of a search bar, and I don't want to trigger the search while the user is typing. I only want to trigger the search when the user submits the form. Therefore, I had to create a new state variable (I'm using hooks), and the code looks like this:

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState(DEFAULT_VALUE);
const [submittedSearchTerm, setSubmittedSearchTerm] = useState(DEFAULT_VALUE);

useEffect(() => {
  // fetch search results
}, [submittedSearchTerm]);

...

function handleChange(e) {
  setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
}

function handleSubmit(e) {
  setSubmittedSearchTerm(searchTerm);
  e.preventDefault();
}

// Simplified
return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input value={searchTerm} onChange={handleChange} />
  </form>
);
```

Basically, `submittedSearchTerm` is a snapshot of `searchTerm` at the time the user submits the form. This works, but it feels weird having to duplicate the state.

Is there a common way to more elegantly solve this problem?

Comment: This looks perfectly fine for the scenarios you've described. You're not really duplicating, but rather snapshotting like you said. One state element is tracking what's being typed in a textbox, and the other one is tracking the query that's being searched for, and the way you've distinguished them seems elegant and correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to do a fetch on component render, what's wrong with just doing this:

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState(DEFAULT_VALUE);

useEffect(() => {
  // do stuff that should be done on component render
}, []);

...

function handleChange(e) {
  setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
}

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // fetch search results
}

// Simplified
return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input value={searchTerm} onChange={handleChange} />
  </form>
);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think you need to duplicate state of that input if I understand your question. Why not to fetch inside `handleSubmit` like:

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  // fetch here
}
```

In case you want to optimize, use `useCallback` and previous function won't be created each render cycle:

```js
const handleSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  // fetch here
}, [])
```

For more complex forms I recommend this lib https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik