# How to pass the data input from one component into another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, openweathermap

### Introducing The Problem

I am **beginner** ReactJS learner developing a simple weather app using OpenWeather API. The app is designed to fetch data from two components: one that returns the current weather of the user input and another one that returns the weather forecast for the next 5 days.

When the city name is typed down into the input field, the following message appears on the console:

> GET [https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=undefined&units=metric&appid=${Api.key}](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=undefined&units=metric&appid=$%7BApi.key%7D) 400 (Bad Request)

I do not know how to pass the data from Search Component into App Component. Seriously, I have tried a lot of alternatives but they have been unsuccessful. There are commented lines of code to show my last try so far.

(ignore ForecastWeather because this component is empty)

I know that all of you are **quite busy folks**, but I would appreciate the help in a respectful way. Even suggestions about what I have to study (e.g. callBack) are welcome. I've tried this already:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56943427/whether-to-save-form-input-to-state-in-onchange-or-onsubmit-in-react

> https://sebhastian.com/react-onchange/

The code is forward below:

### App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Api } from "./Api";
import {
  Search,
  CurrentWeather,
  ForecastWeather,
  Footer,
} from "./components/index";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [getCity, setGetCity] = useState();
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState(null);
  const [forecastData, setForecastData] = useState(null);

  const handleSearchLocation = (dataSearch) => {
    const weatherDataFetch = fetch(
      `${Api.url}/weather?q=${getCity}&units=metric&appid=${Api.key}`
    );
    const forecastDataFetch = fetch(
      `${Api.url}/forecast?q=${getCity}&units=metric&appid=${Api.key}`
    );

    Promise.all([weatherDataFetch, forecastDataFetch])
      .then(async (response) => {
        const weatherResponse = await response[0].json();
        const forecastResponse = await response[1].json();

        setGetCity(dataSearch);
        setWeatherData(weatherResponse);
        setForecastData(forecastResponse);
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Search
        searchResultData={handleSearchLocation}
        textPlaceholder="Search for a place..."
      />
      {weatherData && <CurrentWeather resultData={weatherData} />}
      <ForecastWeather resultData={forecastData} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### Search.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Search({ textPlaceholder, searchResultData }) {
  const [searchCity, setSearchCity] = useState("");

  //const handlerOnChange = ( event, dataSearch ) => {
  //setSearchCity(event.target.value);
  //setSearchCity(dataSearch);
  //searchResultData(dataSearch);
  //};

  return (
    <div className="componentsBoxLayout">
      <input
        value={searchCity}
        //onChange={handlerOnChange}
        onChange={(event) => setSearchCity(event.target.value)}
        onKeyDown={(event) => event.key === "Enter" && searchResultData(event)}
        placeholder={textPlaceholder}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

### CurrentWeather.jsx

```
import React from "react";

function CurrentWeather({ resultData }) {
  return (
    <div className="componentsBoxLayout">
      <p>{resultData.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CurrentWeather;
```

### ForecastWeather.jsx (empty)

```
import React from 'react';

function ForecastWeather() {
  return (
    <div className="componentsBoxLayout">ForecastWeather</div>
  )
}

export default ForecastWeather;
```

### Api.js

```
const Api = {
  url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5",
  key: "etcetc",
  img: "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn",
};

export { Api };
```

Yippee-ki-yay

Comment: You use `setGetCity` after using `weatherDataFetch`. How would you expect it to be defined?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Thank you for your time but even if your help, I am not able to understand how to use setGetCity before weatherDataFetch. I've tried placing before `const weatherDataFetch = fetch(` or passing as an argument or empty string and the same issue persists. All the best.

Comment: I don't understand how you want to ask for weather data for a city without knowing the city first. You have a `Search` component, but you never use the data from this component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use getCity in this function:

```
const handleSearchLocation = (dataSearch) => {
    const weatherDataFetch = fetch(
      `${Api.url}/weather?q=${getCity}&units=metric&appid=${Api.key}`
    );
    const forecastDataFetch = fetch(
      `${Api.url}/forecast?q=${getCity}&units=metric&appid=${Api.key}`
    );

    Promise.all([weatherDataFetch, forecastDataFetch])
      .then(async (response) => {
        const weatherResponse = await response[0].json();
        const forecastResponse = await response[1].json();

        setGetCity(dataSearch);
        setWeatherData(weatherResponse);
        setForecastData(forecastResponse);
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  };
```

getCity is defined on that function so it does not exist when you try to use it, unless you need getCity later for another component I would delete it becuase is redundant and do this:

```
const handleSearchLocation = (dataSearch) => {
    const weatherDataFetch = fetch(
      `${Api.url}/weather?q=${dataSearch}&units=metric&appid=${Api.key}`
    );
    const forecastDataFetch = fetch(
      `${Api.url}/forecast?q=${dataSearch}&units=metric&appid=${Api.key}`
    );

    Promise.all([weatherDataFetch, forecastDataFetch])
      .then(async (response) => {
        const weatherResponse = await response[0].json();
        const forecastResponse = await response[1].json();

        setWeatherData(weatherResponse);
        setForecastData(forecastResponse);
      })
      .catch(console.log);
  };
```

When you run searchResultData on the search component you send the city you are looking for. Remember that useState will trigger a re-render but a function that is already running before that will never get the new value of the state if the state changes

Comment: Thank you so much for what you have done.  This change is working but another problem came up: a 404 error. Then, I update the following line from the Search component: 

`onKeyDown={(event) => event.key === "Enter" && searchResultData(searchCity)}`

I've changed the searchResultData props from event to searchCity.

Comment: is the 404 on the API?

Comment: Not in the API itself, I believe. This was the error:

`GET https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=[object%20Object]&units=metric&appid=fc8975bd4701139dcd78e2e288cc3807 404 (Not Found)`

But now it's ok.

Comment: You need to make sure the value of the input is sent correctly, what I can see is that you are not storing the value correctly on the state

Comment: I will paste the current code of Search and currentWeather: `import React, { useState } from "react";

function Search({ textPlaceholder, searchResultData }) {
  const [searchCity, setSearchCity] = useState("");
  
  return (
    <div className="componentsBoxLayout">
      <input
        value={searchCity}
        onChange={(event) => setSearchCity(event.target.value)}
        onKeyDown={(event) => event.key === "Enter" && searchResultData(searchCity)}
        placeholder={textPlaceholder}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Search;`

Comment: `import React from "react";

function CurrentWeather({ resultData }) {
  return (
    <div className="componentsBoxLayout">
      <p>{resultData.name}</p>
      <p>{resultData.weather[0].description}</p>
      <p>{Math.round(resultData.main.temp)}°C</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CurrentWeather;`

Comment: I have tested the current code and it should be working, please check this and this can help you out https://playcode.io/938760

Comment: Thanks for the help! (I don't know why my answer was not published days ago, then sorry for the late reply).